# Python Polars: Apply function to two columns and an argument

Tags: python, python-polars

#### Intro

In Polars I would like to do quite complex queries, and I would like to simplify the process by dividing the operations into methods. Before I can do that, I need to find out how to provide these function with multiple columns and variables.

#### Example Data

```
# Libraries
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

# Data
test_data = pl.DataFrame({
    "class": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    "date": [datetime(2020, 1, 31), datetime(2020, 2, 28), datetime(2021, 1, 31),
              datetime(2022, 1, 31), datetime(2023, 2, 28),
              datetime(2020, 1, 31)],
    "status": [1,0,1,0,1,0]
})
```

#### The Problem

For each group, I would like to know if a reference date overlaps with the year-month in the date column of the dataframe.

I would like to do something like this.

```
# Some date
reference_date = datetime(2020, 1, 2)

# What I would expect the query to look like
(test_data
 .groupby("class")
 .agg([
    pl.col("status").count().alias("row_count"), #just to show code that works
    pl.lit(reference_date).alias("reference_date"),
    pl.col(["date", "status"])
        .apply(lambda group: myfunc(group, reference_date))
        .alias("point_in_time_status")
 ])
)

# The desired output
pl.DataFrame({
  "class": ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  "reference_date": [datetime(2020, 1, 2), datetime(2020, 1, 2), datetime(2020, 1, 2)],
  "point_in_time_status": [1,0,0]
})
```

But I can simply not find any solutions for doing operations on groups. Some suggest using pl.struct, but that just outputs some weird object without columns or anything to work with.

#### Example in R of the same operation

```
# Loading library
library(tidyverse)

# Creating dataframe
df <- data.frame(
 date = c(as.Date("2020-01-31"), 
          as.Date("2020-02-28"), as.Date("2021-01-31"), 
          as.Date("2022-01-31"), as.Date("2023-02-28"), 
          as.Date("2020-01-31")), 
 status = c(1,0,1,0,1,0), 
 class = c("A","A","A","B","B","C"))

# Finding status in overlapping months
ref_date = as.Date("2020-01-02")

df %>%
  group_by("class") %>%
  filter(format(date, "%Y-%m") == format(ref_date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  filter(status == 1)
```

Comment: You generally want to avoid "apply", it looks like you want to find out if the date is between the min/max per group? e.g. `df.group_by("class").agg(point_in_time_status = pl.lit(reference_date).is_between(pl.col("date").min(), pl.col("date").max()))`

Comment: Why do I want to avoid "apply"? Also, my specific question is for "custom methods". Finally, it is not between dates. There is a list of dates for each class, and I want to: 1) find the matching date based on month/year, and after find out if that line has the column 1

Comment: The idea is Polars Expressions (fast/parallel/Rust) are there to avoid the need for executing [custom functions.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_elements.html#polars.Expr.map_elements) (slow/sequential/Python) As per your update, I guess it's something like: `.agg(((pl.col("date").dt.to_string("%Y-%m") == pl.lit(reference_date).dt.to_string("%Y-%m")) & (pl.col("status") == 1)).any())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with expressions

```
reference_date = datetime(2020, 1, 2)
(
    test_data
    .group_by('class', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
       point_in_time_status = (
         (pl.col('date').dt.month_start() == pl.lit(reference_date).dt.month_start()) & 
         (pl.col('status')==1)
       ).any(),
       reference_date = pl.lit(reference_date)
    )
)
```

I'm using the [`month_start`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.month_start.html) method instead of converting to a string format as strings aren't especially performant if they can be avoided. You can see in the `agg` that we're looking for times when the first day of `date`'s month  is the same as the first day of `reference date`'s month & if status == 1. That is all in parenthesis and then the aggregate `any` function is applied to that which applies per `class`. Lastly, we add in the `reference_date` column to get that in the output. You can interchange the order of those if you like.

You can make that into a method but you should do it with polars expressions otherwise you're going to lose the efficiency gains that polars brings to the table. You can then monkey patch those to the pl.Expr namespace or [create your own namespace](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.api.register_expr_namespace.html)

As an example you could do:

```
def myFunc(self, reference_date, status):
    return (
        (self.dt.month_start()==reference_date.dt.month_start()) &
        (status==1)
    ).any()
pl.Expr.myFunc=myFunc
(
    test_data
    .group_by('class', maintain_order=True)
    .agg(
        point_in_time_status = pl.col('date').myFunc(
         pl.lit(reference_date), pl.col('status')
        ),
        reference_date=pl.lit(reference_date)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out a bit later today and let you know how it works out :) My friend who is a maintainer on the Rust version of Polars also send me a suggestion using "Struct" objects, but I think yours looks more clean.

Comment: is there are way to avoid the "pl.Expr.myFunc=myFunc" expression? Can I not just apply a function in some other way?

Comment: sure. just replace `pl.col('date').myFunc(
         pl.lit(reference_date), pl.col('status')
        )` with `myFunc(pl.col('date'), pl.lit(reference_date), pl.col('status'))`

Comment: Is the "maintain order" part important?

Comment: depends, do you want to maintain the original order or have the results be in an arbitrary order?

Comment: I don't care about the order :) Just wanted to make sure :D